# How to make QML component (widget) adjusts according to data

Tags: qt, widget, qml

I have a Widget as QML component in Qt Quick application which is to be used in various screens to display contents.

How can I use this particular QML component to adjust according to the items in it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it's a generic `Item` you can't: you have to manually set the container's size to fit its content.

The only QML components that fits their content are the `Row`, `Column` and `Grid` elements.

Answer (score 0):

coming in way late, but if you want to have an update-able component you can set the model for the component to any list model like:

```
Component{
    id:comp1
    model:model1
}

ListModel {
            id: model1
            ListElement{
                name:"a"
            }

            ListElement{
                name: "b"
            }
        }

        Component {
            id: fruitDelegate
            Row {
                spacing: 10
                Text { text: name }

            }
        }

        ListView {
            id:listView1
            anchors.fill: parent
            model: fruitModel
            delegate: fruitDelegate
            contentWidth: Screen.width
        }
```

then you can update the listview at will

```
TextInput{
    id: text_input1
    width:parent.width * 0.80

    text:"waddup?"
}
Button {
    id: button2

    anchors.left: text_input1.right
    text: qsTr("Send")
    onClicked: {

        listView1.model.append( {name: text_input1.text, colorCode:"Red" });

        /*text_input1.text = ""*/
    }
}
```